# GSON avoid the JsonSyntaxException return the partial mapping

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, gson

I'm getting this issue, I do not want to solve that issue but find to way to say to GSON "skip errors and continue" parsing :

```
Can't parses json : java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 16412
```

Code used:

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(data));
reader.setLenient(true);
Articles articles = gson.create().fromJson(reader, Articles.class);
```

The data are (to simplify) : Articles->Pages->medias.fields. One field in the current error is defined as string but I'm receiving an object (but again it is only one occurrence). I cannot add protection everywhere so my question is: **"is there a skip and continues in GSON ?**

I want to avoid JsonSysntaxException with GSON when there is an issue on a node and I expect at least to retrieve the partial data parsed. In my case I would have had 99.999% of the data and only my wrong field as null… I know it seems not clean, but I would enable the "strict mode" for unit test or continous integration to detect problem and on production I would enable a "soft mode" so my application could start (even when the server side doing errors). I cannot say to my custom, your app cannot start because an article has an invalide data.

**Is GSON have a "skip and continue on error" ?**

Comment: can u post the response from the web-service , it will help more to solve ur problem

Comment: I added the code and I do not want to fixe this issue but find a way to not trigger this exception when only a leaf/a node is impacted by a bad format. Is it possible ?

Comment: @Gros we need to see the actual JSON code you're trying to parse!

Comment: @MikO My question is not what is the problem and help me to fix this specific issues. I know where is the issue and how to fix it. My problem is more, if there is a structure issue somewhere in the json is there a way to "skip and continue" in GSON ? There are a lot of objects so I do not want to past unusefull information. To give a overview I have some articles (array)-> with pages-> with medias. One media a variable as a string but in the json it is an object (but only one time). Note: the issue can appear somewhere else so I cannot do specifics.

Comment: @Gros ok, but then you should at least explain a bit what do you mean by *structure issue*, because depending on that the solution can be different... is it invalid JSON? or is it that somewhere in the JSON the structure of an object is not as expected? or what? some sample pieces of JSON code could help here...

Comment: @MikO I updated my global description so it should be more clear. (I couldn't update my incomplet last comment before your reply :p)

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution:
You have to create TypeAdapterFactory which will allow you to intercept default TypeAdapter, 
but still leave to you access to default TypeAdapter as a delegate. 
Then you can just try to read value using delegate from default TypeAdapter and process unexpected data as you wish.

```
      public Gson getGson() {

                return new GsonBuilder()
                            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new LenientTypeAdapterFactory())
                .create();
            }


        class LenientTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

                public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {

                    final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);

                    return new TypeAdapter<T>() {

                        public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                            delegate.write(out, value);
                        }

                        public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                            try { //Here is the magic
//Try to read value using default TypeAdapter
                                return delegate.read(in); 
                            } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
//If we can't in case when we expecting to have an object but array is received (or some other unexpected stuff), we just skip this value in reader and return null
                                in.skipValue(); 
                                return null;
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is correct answer! It should be marked as such

Answer (score 2):

I think that the answer is simply: no, generally it can't.

Due to the recursive parsing nature of the library if something is wrong, it would throw some kind of exception. It would interesting if you could post a SSCCE of your problem to experiment if it is possible to create a customized type adapter that handle better exceptions.